# UITableView: Hide cells animated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make some of my cells of a `UITableView` invisible. Pushing a button they are supposed to toggle the visibility.
I tried the `Hidden` property of the `UITableViewCell` class but it cannot be animated. Setting the cell's `Frame` to a height of 0 will make the cell small, but not hidden and it does not animate either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should use is `[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` method. Make sure to adjust your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method to reflect the number of rows that have been deleted or your app will crash.

Comment: I get this: "NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 4 deleted)."
No matter if I adjust numberOfRowsInSection before or after deleting the rows. (I'm deleting them in my controller)

Comment: I wonder if there is a miscalculation of either a) which and how many rows to delete or b) how your controller calculates how many rows should be there after the deletion. If you post the code where you delete, as well as your numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Failed to count up to 7! :-)

Comment: This deletes the cell rather than hides it.  If you wish to temporarily hide a cell, say when you are editing something in only particular cells, this won't do it.